# Apache Atlas Rest Api

Tags: rest, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-atlas

Im trying to read an Atlas entitiy via rest api, i tried this command :

```
curl -v -i -s -X GET user:pwd@something.confidential.here:21000/v1/entities/branch_intersect
```

Although i can see the table in Apache UI but it says not found :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /v1/entities/branch_intersect. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Im using Atlas v 0.7 and following this [doc](http://atlas.apache.org/0.7.0-incubating/api/resource_EntityService.html#path__v1_entities.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest url should be like this :

```
curl -v -i -s -X GET user:pwd@something.confidential.here:21000/api/atlas/
```

Reference [here](http://atlas.apache.org/AtlasTechnicalUserGuide.pdf)